# 'Обещать'/'сулить'

Tags: значения

Еще один вопрос относительно значения -- в чем разница между `обещать` и `сулить`? Сулить -- более литературное слово? Оно когда-нибудь употребляется в неформальном общении, но более редко чем 'обещать'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Сулить** можно только вещи или явления (тогда как **обещать** можно и совершение обещающим неких действий) — и само употребление слова **сулить** обычно означает, что эти вещи или явления однозначно желательны для того, кому сулят, вплоть до соблазнительности и/или нереалистичности.

Упрощая, можно сказать, что сулить — это искушать обещанием.

Answer (score 2):

Они взаимозаменяемы в значении "*предвещать*", "*предсказывать*", "*вселять надежду на*".  У "*обещать*" есть ещё другое значение - "*давать обязательство*".

В неформальном общении слово "*сулить*" осталось только в составе идиоматических сочетаний: сулить победу, сулить удачу, что сулит нам 2016 год?

Answer (score 1):

Оба слова имеют примерно одно и то же значение, однако слово `сулить` в повседневной жизни употребляется значительно реже и, на мой взгляд, его даже можно считать устаревающим.

Comment: (sorry, I misclicked and added to your post instead of my own; reverted.)